# Effects of Changing Area Path in VSTS?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

My questions are listed at the end of this post but reading the background info first will help understand the context of the questions.

**Background**

I've had some *limited* experience working with TFS (on-premise) as a development team member in the past, and I'm generally familiar with the basic concepts. But now I'm also tasked with administering a VSTS instance (cloud). Most of my experience using TFS was centered around the project management features (backlogs, sprints, work items, etc.).

I'm rolling out VSTS in 2 phases. The first phase focuses on the non-technical project management aspects of the configuration. The second phase will focus on technical aspects such as managing source code and other development artifacts. I have some experience working with the source control aspects using TFVC repository, but no experience with Git repository.

I completed the preliminary design of the basic configuration (Teams, Area Path, Iteration Path, etc.) for VSTS. I suspect that my Area Path will need adjustment at some point in the near future. From what I've read, VSTS does a decent job of automatically updating Work Items (e.g. Features, Product Backlog Items, Tasks, etc.) when changes to the Area Path are made.

**Questions**

What I'd like to know is how other technical areas of the product (e.g. code repositories, build definitions, etc.) are affected when changes are made to Area Path. For example, if I inserted a completely new node somewhere within the Area Path, how badly will that "break" existing VSTS functionality (and what type of functionality will be broken and require *manual* repair)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an easy one:

Area paths only affect work item tracking. Period.